# calculating a row value in pandas with a previously calculated value using .apply and lambda

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

this code gives the result i want:

- it takes the value n-1 and calculates n from it

take the previous value in column 'y' lets call it y-1 and calculate a value which becomes the new y, than in the next row take that new y as y-1 and calculate another new y aso

```
size = 10
x= range(1,size+1)
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': x,'y': size })

for n in range(1,len(x)):
    df['y'].iloc[n] = df['y'].iloc[n-1]*2

out:

    x   y
0   1   10
1   2   20
2   3   40
... ... ...
9   10  5120
```

I want to put it into a lambda but somehow fail to get it right:

```
b=2
df['y'].loc[1::] = df['y'].shift(-1).apply(lambda x: x*b)

out:

    x   y
0   1   10.0
1   2   20.0
2   3   20.0
... ... ...
```

the lambda function takes the pre-populated value (10) in each row instead of shifting 1 step back and taking the previous value as base for the multiplication

i looked at some threads, but its above my comprahension, if i am dealing here with recursion and this is not possible with lambdas?

[recursive lambda-expressions possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203292/recursive-lambda-expressions-possible)

[Python Recursion on Pandas df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64661990/python-recursion-on-pandas-df)

[Can a lambda function call itself recursively in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481692/can-a-lambda-function-call-itself-recursively-in-python)

Edit:
I want that subsequent entries in 'y' are calculated with previous 'y' entries, starting from idx 1

```
DataFrame at start:

idx | y |
 0   10


DataFrame after 1st calc:
y1 = y0 *2

# *2 is a placeholder could be mx+b, or something else

idx | y |
 0   10
 1   20
```

Comment: Can you please describe what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need to do any recursion, unless I'm misunderstanding this is mathematical exponents.

Note sure what you're actual use case but something like one of these should work.

```
[v*(2**i) for i,v in enumerate(df.y)]    

df.apply(lambda j: j.y*(2**(j.x-1)), axis=1)
```

Comment: my *2 is just meant as a placholder for a function, ````df['y'].iloc[n-1]*m+b````

Comment: then swap the 2 for `m` and add `b` on no?

Comment: i edited the question, hope to have made things clearer